# Identical Xpath query to a sql2 query?

Tags: xpath, aem, jcr-sql2

I want identical XPATH query to trhis SQL2 Query.

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/content/abc/def]) and ([sling:resourceType] = 'geomatrixx/components/list' )
```

Is there any tool or link available through which i can convert sql2 query into xpath. or any tutorial if yes then please share the link

Comment: The only way I know is with code. If you use the com.day.cq.search.Query class you see the used xpath query in the debugger of the IDE after the method getResult() is called...

Answer (score 2):

Below is the equilvalent XPath query.

```
    /jcr:root/content/abc/def//element(*, cq:Page)[jcr:contains(jcr:content/@sling:resourceType, 'geometrixx/components/list')].
```

Below are some of the **mappings** between **xpath** and **sql2** queries respectively.Taken from http://docs.jboss.org/jbossdna/0.7/manuals/reference/html/jcr-query-and-search.html.

```
      //*                                                SELECT * FROM [nt:base]
      //element(*,my:type)                               SELECT * FROM [my:type]
     //element(*,my:type)/@my:title                      SELECT [my:title] FROM [my:type]
     //element(*,my:type)/(@my:title | @my:text)         SELECT [my:title],[my:text] FROM [my:type]
    //element(*,my:type)/(@my:title union @my:text)      SELECT [my:title],[my:text] FROM [my:type]
```

Thanks,
Balaji